# Package names should comply with a naming convention (squid:S00120) and underscore

Tags: java, sonarlint

**SonarLint** produces an error:

`Package names should comply with a naming convention (squid:S00120) ... With the default regular expression ^[a-z]+(\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*)*$.`

However the JLS allows and even recommends using the underscore. Clause 6.1. Declarations says, i.a.,

> If the domain name contains a hyphen, or any other special character
>   not allowed in an identifier (§3.8), convert it into an underscore.

Can I change the regular expression or must it be fixed in the product?

Comment: Underscores and capital letters are *legal* in package names, but they're widely considered bad style.

Comment: I have no problem with banning capital letters, but one cannot comply with another clause in the JLS without the underscore: "You form a unique package name by first having (or belonging to an organization that has) an Internet domain name, such as oracle.com. You then reverse this name, component by component, ..., and use this as a prefix for your package names, using a convention developed within your organization to further administer package names." My domain is www.qsm-fss.com. So it cannot be bad style to have an underscore in a package name.

Comment: The domain-name-based package naming algorithm is non-normative, right? It is very widely violated in practice.

Comment: It is not normative but it is strongly recommended, even with Java 9. I cannot see how a JLS recommendation could be considered bad style.

Comment: I'd ask the sonarlint people why they flag it as an error when someone is following a naming convention from the JLS.

Comment: I posted the same issue on the Google group.

Comment: FWIW I would say that even having a domain name with a hyphen in it is "bad style" of a sort. I don't know of any organization that *only* owns a domain name with a hyphen... to be honest, if I were in that situation I'd think about registering an alternative domain name anyway.

Comment: And refactor hundreds of classes the followed the recommendation?

Comment: I would *tell* the sonarlint people to *stop* enforcing a different (tighter) constraint than what is *specified* in the JLS. They are 100% wrong to do so.

Comment: SonalLint responded in the Google group: You are right, it was an oversight on our side and since it's not yet possible to change rule parameters from SonarLint in standalone mode, it is a major annoyance.
I've created a ticket to fix this: SONARJAVA-2596

Comment: Thanks but the bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) server. You can connect your SonarLint plugin to the server and manipulate the way SL performs SCA in your IDE.

One of the nicer features of SQ is the ability to disable SCA rules and remove them from all future scan. Using this feature, you can disable the package name rule (which I also find annoying),a and not have it clutter up the editing view.

Another option is to create a new rule, which will enforce a new regular expression convention on the package names - for example, allowing package names to be Camel Case.

Finally, as stated by [Jonathan Rosenne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2036983/jonathan-rosenne) in a comment to the question, the package name issue SONARJAVA-2596 which Jonathan had opened following this question has been fixed, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/commit/50b1cedb5959111b2ebd0b81a1d01a89cd6136dc).

Reference:

- [How to disable a rule in SonarQube](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/24734/how-to-deactivate-a-rule-in-sonarqube)
- [Writing Custom Java Rules 101](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101)

Comment: Using an external server is not appropriate to sensitive software.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne : The SQ server is an on-premise server - it  resides on your private cloud and is not exposed outside of your organization. One simply downloads the SQ installation and creates a dedicated SQ server in the internal private cloud.

Comment: Good to know if we ever need it.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne : I highly recommend using Static Code Analysis tools as a part of any organization's CI/CD flow. I have seen multiple examples of critical issues being exposed prior to the release of an official version thanks to SQ/SL.

Comment: We are using SonarLint, StopBugs and CheckStyle. Could you suggest anything else?

Comment: Well, after reviewing the following SCA list : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java - I can say that I know a little about JTest from previous experience in Automation and ThreadSafe which I did not personally use. JTest is interesting thanks to its ability to consolidate automation testing and SCA, which is synergistic IMHO. ThreadSafe I heard about from friends who worked on highly multi-threaded environments and they mentioned it as a life-saver. Add a code coverage tool and your CI should be close to perfect.