# package naming issue in sonarqube

Tags: java, sonarqube

when I run my jar in sonarqube for code coverage I m getting as rename this package name to match the regular expression the package name which is gave is routeBuilder.Can some one please let me know how to change this ?

tried changing it to route builder everything in lower case.

package com.sample.loading.routeBuilder

Answer (score 2):

What you've hit is https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/convention/RSPEC-120.

This rule states that the name of the package should conform to a regular expression, which does not allow capital letters.

To fix the SQ warning, you should correct your package name to `com.sample.loading.routebuilder` or `com.sample.loading.route_builder`.

Note that the current default expression now allows underscores. Earlier it had not, which has been discussed here [Package names should comply with a naming convention (squid:S00120) and underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858665/package-names-should-comply-with-a-naming-convention-squids00120-and-undersco).